# Creating instances of React containers but need each with their own Redux property

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a parent Container/Component that is hooked into redux. It's somewhat of a form builder.

It will have children components that are also going to be Containers. I do not know how many, this will be built by a JSON payload.

There will be times where I will have 2 or more of the same type of child.

How do I separate them so I know the redux state of each child container when they are the same type of component?

Is there a way my redux store could look like this:

Parent: {
    child1: reduxData,
    child2: reduxData,
}

When creating the two children they override each other in the store.

Answer (score 0):

You can design your store like a dictionary (normalize pattern):

```
const todos = {}
```

Then each new todo (or entity in your case) will be stored by a key:

```
const todos = {
  'xf2': { text: 'Foobar', checked: false },
  'xf3': { text: 'Qwerty', checked: false },
}
```

With this pattern, you can have as many children as you need in their own context.
If you want to know more about normalizing your state check this [link](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) from Redux Docs.